# Preventing HTTP REQUEST on javascript DOM update

Tags: dom, browser, updates, reflow

I am getting re-execution of imported js files upon a hitting a form button which calls a function to insert a DOM element into page ( in simulation to exe of an ajx callback function). The DOM insertion causes a page refresh which re-requests all files from server.

Nothing big on the function call:

```
var addFashionVideo = function() {

var nodeContainer = document.getElementById('vidList');
var mytitle = document.forms.addVideo.newVidName.value;
var addTextNode = document.createTextNode(mytitle);
var newLI = document.createElement('LI');
newLI.appendChild(addTextNode);
nodeContainer.appendChild(newLI);

return this;

};
```

TARGET DIV for DOM update code is :

```
<div id="ajParent" class="aj" style="width:325px;background-color:blue;color:white;">

<ul id="vidList">
<li><a href="javascript://" title="FashVid-Paris">Watch Fashion Paris Video</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

---

I place an alert on this page and after the function attempts to insert the new LI 
[ oddly the LI appears for a split second then disappears ] a page refresh is triggered
and my alert on the page re-executes.

// Perhaps Maybe I have a browser issue on this computer or I am just to new of a scripter
// to not see the problem...any comment appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a little code of a link to the site. I might be wrongly reading your question but I don't think adding an element to the page would cause your scripts to re-executue.

Comment: I have a Live Headers plugin for Firefox, so I can see the get requests are being made after I hit the submit button for a js DOM 

-----
Here is the DOM function update 
var addFashionVideo = function() {

alert("we hit the Add fashion Video func");

var nodeContainer = document.getElementById('vidList');
var mytitle = document.forms.addVideo.newVidName.value;

alert("Entry of New Title is :" + mytitle);

var addTextNode = document.createTextNode(mytitle);

var newLI = document.createElement('LI');

newLI.appendChild(addTextNode);



nodeContainer.appendChild(newLI);

return this;

};

Comment: The alerts contained in the imported head tag js files  fire off as soon as I invoke this in page DOM function. So everything is refreshed..

Comment: @Todd You should be able to edit your question. Adding your code will make it easier to read and get you a few more responses from people who have more experience in this then me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The minute you hit submit on a form, the page will reload since you have made a GET request with the form. In order to stop the form from submitting you would have to make it return false on submit. e.g.

```
document.getElementById('formname').onsubmit = function {
  return false; 
};
```

You would have to make sure to disable form submission so the page doesn't reload, then you could run your ajax request on submission and do what you must on success in the ajax function.

I really doubt your dom insertion is causing the reload.